# Errors while importing users from old site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have an old drupal site with 100 users. However when I tried importing them all in new drupal instance I got errors like below for most of user entries.

```
Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to 
int in drupal_write_record() (line 7159 of sitepath\includes\common.inc
```

I'm using the Drupal [data export import module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import).

Is this serious, as I can see users imported but not sure if this error give me problem later. 
Or is there any better way of importing user from old Drupal site.

Note: both sites are running on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Data Export Import module is not very maintained. Last commit 9 months ago.

I see two options:

- Create View with a CSV on the old site, then use [User Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_import) to import the CSV.
- If you have coding capabilities around (and experience with Drupal coding) and you need more customization you should go for [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate).

Comment: I m migrating users from same drupal version e.g old Drupal 7 to new Drupal 7 so I think Migrate is not a right solution (as per the doc its for migrating from different CMS to drupal. ) . How to create views with a CSV ? will i be able to import the user profile Images ?